# How to get htmlAction id from my controller?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

The url manage to parse the id over e.g. "mylink/Index/1" however it didn't read my id on the following line.

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Submit school rating", "Index", "Review", new { id = Model.School_Code }, new { name = "Index" })
```

**Controller** (Review Model)

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, ReviewSearch model)
        {
            reviews = revGateway.SelectAll();
            if (id == 0)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            reviews = reviews.Where(s => s.School_Code.Equals(id));

            if (reviews == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;
            model.SearchResults = reviews.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);

            return View(model);
        }
```

**View** (School Model)

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Submit school rating", "Index", "Review", new { id = Model.School_Code }, new { name = "Index" })
```

Comment: What makes you think the `id` parameter is not bound. Based on the code you have shown, id the value of `Model.School_Code` is a valid `int`, then it will be correctly bound.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your code. I was able to get the id by the same way. Just make sure that if Model.School_Code has some value or not. Try to pass some hard core value first and check if you are able to get that value or not.

You can also get the same value by using RouteData like this:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        int id;
        int.TryParse(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString(), out id);

        return View();
    }
```

View

@Html.ActionLink("Submit school rating", "Test", "Default", new { id = 1 }, new { name = "Index" })

Comment: nope. it didn't even work when i hardcode some value to the ActionLink. replied with "Bad Request"

Comment: remove all other things and just try with plain action like I showed above. It should work if you are able to go to controller. Debug and try to see if you can